# How to write a TypeScript primitive type extension method that is being type-checked

Tags: typescript, extension-methods, typechecking

In TypeScript, I would like to add extension methods to primitive types in such a way so that parameter and return types are type-checked at transpile-time.

So far, however, I have not succeeded. I have found many useful threads about this subject, none of which offer a solution. Since all I have found is quite dated, I would like to raise this topic again.

This is what I tried so far:

```
declare global {
    interface String {
        myCoolMethod(inputValue: number): string;
    }
}        

String.prototype.myCoolMethod = function (inputValue: number): string {
    return this + inputValue.toString();
};
```

And the same in a different way:

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "myCoolMethod", {
        value: function myCoolMethod(inputValue: number) : string {
            return this + inputValue.toString();
            },
            writable: true,
            configurable: true
        }
    );
```

These snippets work, but no type-checking at transpile time and no intellisense warnings in the (Visual Studio) editor. I am on VS2019 with TypeScript 3.7.

Is there (now) a way of combining type-checking and extension methods in TypeScript?

---

### Update:

See my answer below, where I point out the real issue (to myself, and to whoever may benefit...)

Comment: It seems to [work fine to me](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpiqA5sg3gKGSOQFsBPAYQHsqAbAWQjAAsqATAClAAcBXMAGpxavCAC5kIXiQBG0AJQSAzhmwBufAF98+dJhBYAdNyhUwZstwiHy1OoxbtkAXmQxeIBGGBUQyLiB8gsKiElKyCsqqBniExFBMvFB+LMBKyADUyDz8QiLW5nrYHPIamhr4CL4qyOmuAETMELS0VPUaVSBKdNatWBxKNpQ0DEysnACMAEwAzPKlyAD0i8hNLVTTM-iDtiMO4xz1NNxK9QvLyNCmUAA0kmbIcJLSclD4QA).  Is this specifically a question about your IDE?

Comment: @jcalz thank you for pointing out that the code indeed does work. I figured out the reason for me not getting the type error and updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question so I can mark it as solved:

The issue is an entirely different one than I originally thought. As jcalz pointed out, this indeed gives me a type error, as expected:

```
const s = "hello";
console.log(s.myCoolMethod(123)); // hello123
s.myCoolMethod("oops"); // error, not a number
```

but in my consuming code, I had this, *not* giving me an error:

```
somebodysPackage.somebodysFunction().join(", ").myCoolMethod("oops");  // no error
```

Although the Javascript function join() always returns a string, TypeScript does not find my String extension method, although it is correctly executed by Javascript at runtime.

However, casting somebodysFunction's result to string[] changes this:

```
(somebodysPackage.somebodysFunction()) as string[]).join(", ").myCoolMethod("oops");  // type error
```

Now, TypeScript knows the input type to join() and can infer the output tye and my extension function is correctly located and the type error thrown.

FInally, installing type declaration files for `somebodysPackage` from npm solved the issue without the explicit cast.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the extensions to the interface in an `index.d.ts` file (or your root types file):

```
interface String {
  myCoolMethod(input: number): string;
}
```

Then create a separate file with the method implementation:

```
// strProto.ext.ts
String.prototype.myCoolMethod = function (inputValue: number): string {
  return this + inputValue.toString();
};
```

and import that file:

```
import '../types/strProto.ext'
```

This should give you access to the method with type safety as well. Tested on TS 3.7 in VSCode.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer my question. It turned out that I had applied my extension method to a not-strongly-typed variable (see my updated answer). After I strongly-typed the variable where the method is being applied to, it works as expected.